# using request data in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

I'm playing around with an API. What I'm trying to is print last names onto a html doc.

So I was able to console log the list object that response gave me, and loop trough it to find last names. But this is where I'm stuck, how do I print to a document? Do I write a function in app.get, or do I can access the data from the HTML doc?

A little lost, any help would be awesome.

Thanks.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var nationbuilder = require('nationbuilder');
var OAuth2 = nationbuilder.auth.OAuth2;
var async = require('async');

var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(); 
var sites = nationbuilder.sites('v1');
var people = nationbuilder.people('v1');

//look for resources.
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')) ;

//nationbuilder config.
oauth2Client.setCredentials({
    access_token: 'XXXXXXX'
});
nationbuilder.options({
    params: {
        slug: 'XXXXXXXX',
    },
    auth: oauth2Client
}); 

people.list(function(err , response){
    for( var i = 0; i < response.results.length; i++){
        var last_name = response.results[i].last_name;
        console.log(last_name)
    }
});

app.get('/', function(request, response){
    response.sendfile('index.html');
});
app.listen(3000)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options here. What you're doing now is simply sending the static HTML file which doesn't allow the modification of a webpage.

Option one, which is probably your best bet, is the use of a HTML render engine, like [Pug](http://jade-lang.com/). [Others are available](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html).

Basic usage (copied from above link):

`index.pug`

```
html
  head
    title= title
  body
    h1= message
```

`index.js`

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Hey', message: 'Hello there!'});
});
```

Which produces the following HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hey</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello there!
    </body>
</html>
```

Another option, which requires more work, is the use of a RESTful API. You'd write a set of endpoints which alter state. Then in your interface you'd have Javascript calling those endpoints and altering the DOM based on the results.

Personally, I'd recommend a template engine as it perfectly suits your needs, it's less work and it is close to what you're trying to do now.

* Disclaimer: I recently needed to use an HTML template engine and I went with Pug. Purely because I knew of its existence. I'm not familiar with any alternatives which is why I didn't mention any others.

Comment: thanks for the input, i think i have to ask a new question now.